# Creating nice form letters for nontechnical users

Tags: datatool, scrlttr2

I am trying to create a more complicated template but created this short example to document what I really want to do.

I want to create a form letter where the user will not see any complicated stuff which could be confusing. For this I want to hide all the datatool stuff

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\myDatabase}[1]{
    \DTLloaddb{test}{#1}%
}

%This is not working:
%\AtBeginDocument{
%   \DTLloaddb{test}{test.csv}%
%   \DTLforeach{test}{\name=Name, \age=Age}{%
%   \begin{letter}
%}
%
%\AtEndDocument{
%       \end{letter}}
%}

\myDatabase{test.csv}

\begin{document}
    \DTLforeach{test}{\name=Name, \age=Age}{% I want to remove this!
    \begin{letter}% I want to remove this!
        Dear Mr. \name
    \end{letter}}% I want to remove this!
\end{document}
```

My database test.csv looks just like this:

```
Name, Age
Alfred, 42
Brian, 23
Conrad, 66
```

My main problem is that splitting the `\DTLForeach` to appear at the beginning and conclude at the end of the document doesn't work. I tried already `\bgroup` and `\egroup` instead of using the bracket but this didn't change anything.

Comment: I know in my example somehow the first letter of "Dear" disappeares. Hints on this are welcome as well.

Comment: I think if your users cannot tolerate any code at all in the document - not even something like `\begin{myletter} ... \end{myletter}`, then you should probably not be expecting them to use LaTeX. What happens when they want to include quotation marks or emphasise something? Don't force LaTeX on them if the whole idea of mark-up is alien. That's cruel and unusual typesetting in my book.

Comment: The problem is not \begin{letter} and \end{letter}. It is the \DTLForeach. This is just a simple example. What i am doing is much more complicated. Since the user won't have to change the loop it is not necessary to see it.

Comment: That's why I said `myletter` and not `letter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the `letter` environment requires an argument, namely the address. This is probably the reason why the word `Dear` or parts of it disappear.

Regarding how to hide the machinery for generating the letters, here is a solution with several elements:

- The definitions can be hidden by putting them into a style file or even a new document class (see below).
- To use the contents of an environment (its body) as argument of another command, use `\NewEnviron` from the package `environ`. Applied to your example:

  ```
  \documentclass{scrlttr2}
  \usepackage{datatool}
  \usepackage{environ}
  \NewEnviron{Letters}[1]{%
    \DTLloaddb{test}{#1}%
    \DTLforeach{test}{\name=Name, \age=Age}{%
      \begin{letter}{\name}
      \BODY
      \end{letter}%
    }%
  }
  \begin{document}
  \begin{Letters}{test.csv}
    \opening{Dear Mr.~\name}
  \end{Letters}
  \end{document}
  ```
- Finally, in order to hide `\begin{documentclass}` and `\end{documentclass}`, you have to use `\aftergroup` and a trick to make `\BODY` available after the `Letters` environment.

Here is the reduced input file:

```
\documentclass{myletters}
\begin{Letters}{test.csv}
  \opening{Dear Mr.~\name}
\end{Letters}
```

Put the following code into the file `myletters.cls`.

```
\ProvidesClass{myletters}[2018/07/20 My special letter class V0.42]
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt]{scrlttr2}
% Define here any special class options
% \DeclareOption{...}{...}
% Pass all others to the underlying class
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrlttr2}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{datatool}
\newcommand\MakeLetters{%
  \begin{document}
    \DTLforeach{test}{\name=Name, \age=Age}{% 
      \begin{letter}{\name}
      \ContentsOfLetter
      \end{letter}%
    }%
  \end{document}%
}

\RequirePackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{Letters}[1]{%
  \DTLloaddb{test}{#1}%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\ContentsOfLetter\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \aftergroup\MakeLetters
}
```

Here is the output of both versions:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: There is an environment version of `\DTLforeach` (`DTLenvforeach` or `DTLenvforeach*`) which could be used instead.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thanks for the suggestion. The environment works fine when used directly in the document, but in a `\newenvironment` command (with `\begin{DTL...}` in the begin-part and `\end{DTL...}` in the end-part) I get the error that the environments are closed in the wrong order. Using `\DTLenvforeach` and `\endDTLenvforeach` also doesn't help. The problem reminds me of the one that I solve by making `\BODY` global and using `\aftergroup`.

Comment: Okay. I'll look into that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I tried to put the Environment into \AtBeginDocument, or. \AtEndDocument and got the Error "\begin{DTLenvforeach} on input line 18 ended by \end{document}.

Comment: @baghira You can try `\DTLenvforeach` instead of `\begin{DTLenvforeach}` and `\endDTLenvforeach` instead of `\end{DTLenvforeach}`. If this doesn't work either, use the `environ` package as I have proposed in my solution.

Comment: @gernot Thanks, i will try it out. Currently I am using your environment-solution. Thanks for it.